# How to specify one had the topmost GPA during his education?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

I am writing a CV and I want to specify that I had the best GPA among all of the students. What is the best way to write such a thing in north america? Does 'Bachelor with first class honor' work? How about 'Bachelor's degree with distinction'?

Comment: In America the system usually is _Cum Laude, Magna Cum Laude,_ and _Summa Cum Laude_. It says on the diploma. So if you got one of those, you say so. Otherwise, not.

Comment: No, I got my certificate from outside USA (non-english) but I am writing the CV for an American company.

Answer (score 3):

My GPA was top of the class / highest in my year.

Comment: This, +1. What is important is not to attempt to "translate" such an achievement into a different system: you couldn't get a First (or a Distinction) if your institution doesn't award that, and to say that you have may be seen as misrepresentation or even an attempt to deceive.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would probably put it under a section titled **honors and certificates**. My friend had *university rank* as we call in our country :) and she mentioned her rank under this section.
 "First class with distinction " is what I saw in another friend's resume under the same "honors and certificates" section. Both of them applied for graduate studies in USA. They also mentioned something about "merit award".

Answer (score -1):

While "valedictorian" technically means "the one who gives the valediction during commencement", it is very often used to mean "the student with the highest grade point average in the graduating class".